# How to print a specific column of a specific row in a html table to the printer?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to print a specific column of a specific row in a html table. I tried CSS and jQuery solutions out there but nothing really helped

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a stylesheet for print media and hide the stuff you dont want to print.

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

Add class of no-print to the columns you dont want to print and set visibility to none in print.css

if this is your table :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class='no-print'>No Print</td>
      <td  class='no-print'>Print</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class='no-print'>No Print</td>
      <td class='no-print'>Print</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class='no-print'>No Print</td>
     <td class='no-print'>Print</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='no-print'>No Print</td>
      <td class='no-print'>Print</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class='no-print'>No Print</td>
     <td class='no-print'>Print</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Other way of doing it would be using pseudo selectors :nth-child()

You can do like this in print.css:

```
table tr td:nth-child(1){
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

It will hide every first column when you print it.